# Run only a single function in a Yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

How can I run only a single function in a generator (and end the generator) if a flag is set? What is the preferred way to achieve this?

```
var MyGenerator = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({

  constructor: function () {
    yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    this.option('flag', {
      desc: 'Do something',
      type: String,
      required: false,
      defaults: null
    });
  },

  runOnlyThisIfFlagIsSet: function() {
    if(this.options.flag) {
      // do stuff and end the generator so that it does all the things defined here
    }   
  },

  doNotRunThis: function() {
    // I don't want this to run if the flag is set
  },

  iCouldDoThisButItIsTooRepetitive: function() {
    if(!this.options.flag) {
      // do stuff
    } 
  }
});

module.exports = MyGenerator;
```

`yo myGeneratorName --flag`

Comment: Do you have an update to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're over thinking this? Based on http://yeoman.io/authoring/running-context.html, I would recommend only having maybe one function in your generator anyway (default?). Read the section called "Helper and private methods" if you want to break your generator into additional methods.

```
var MyGenerator = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({

  constructor: function () {
    yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    this.option('flag', {
      desc: 'Do something',
      type: String,
      required: false,
      defaults: null
    });
  },

  default: function() {
    if(this.options.flag) {
      // do stuff and end the generator so that it does all the things defined here. Use the documentation link above to figure out how to create private methods you can call from here. 
    }    
  }


});

module.exports = MyGenerator;
```

If the flag is not set, the generator will just exit.

Comment: Hi, yes that would be ok if I'd only have that one function. However I have multiple functions in the generator I'm creating that I don't want to run If the flag is set.